# Calculate how much a password complexity criteria lowers the password space

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I am trying to calculate the impact on the overall password complexity of a specific (and questionnable) password criteria.

Lets say that a user has a username of 8 characters (lowercase and upper) and has to choose a new password. The password criterias are the following :

-8 or more characters.

-At least 1 number [0-9].

-At least 1 Uppercase [A-Z].

-At least 1 lowercase [a-z].

-The password must *NOT* contain 3 or more characters (*consecutive or not*) from the username. This is the criteria bothers me.

For example, if a username is "MRSomeone", his password "Smnabc12" would be rejected because it contains S+m+n.

I know this last criteria lowers the possible password space, but how to calculate precisely it's effect (with this criteria vs. without) ?

Comment: Without an upper limit on the password length the space is still infinite (unless of course you have a "mr0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" on the system).

Comment: Then let's pick the specific case of a password length of 8 characters. How would you proceed ?

Comment: You'll need to define a length-restriction on the username as well.

Comment: Then let's pick a username of "Abcdefgh" (8 distinct characters).

Comment: I would like to point out that it doesn't really matter that it makes the password space smaller unless it is really significant.  Consider a brute force attack, if it takes 100 years vs 50 years to crack the password, that doesn't really make a practical difference.  Someone is going to crack your password by guessing common, likely passwords, which these guidelines should discourage people from using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best anwser i've come up so far :

**Hypothesis :**

Username is 8 distinct characters (Abcdefg)

Password is 8 character long (upper, lower, numbers)

Character space : 62 characters (26 lower, 26 upper, 10 numbers)

**Calculations :**

Total combinations without criterias : 62^8 passwords (218 340 105 584 896 combinations)

Total combinations with criterias : 62*62*54^6 passwords (95 311 639 021 824 combinations)

**Explanation :**

First two characters are unrestricted, they can be of any value (62 possible values). Following 6 characters cannot be part of the username (62 - 8 = 54 possible values).

**Conclusion**

In conclusion, with this hypothesis, this criteria reduce the number of passwords by 43,65% ((95 311 639 021 824 / 218 340 105 584 896) * 100) .

**Bonus :**

With any scenario, I can exclude the following combinations which would not be complex enough and rejected :

All numbers : 10^8 combinations

All lowercase : 26^8 combinations

All Uppercase : 26^8 combinations

Only Uppercase and numbers : (26+10)^8 combinations

Only Lowercase and numbers (26+10)^8 combinations

Only Lowercase and uppercase : (26+26)^8 combinations